# Android Studio gets stuck when creating new project

Tags: android, android-studio

After installing Android Studio and updating to 0.5.9, when I try to create a new project, after I get through all the menus, I get stuck at a screen with a progress bar that says "Building 'project_name' Gradle project info". I let it sit there for close to 10 minutes and nothing happened. No errors, no progress bar movement, literally nothing except the process eating up more and more memory.

I've already looked at other posts that were similar to my question, but they haven't helped as I don't even get to the "downloading Gradle" point that are in some other answers on stackoverflow here.

Here's a screencap of the screen I get hung up on:
[image: android studio screencap]

I'm really at a loss here as to what is causing it to get hung up like it is.

Comment: Did you already try rebooting your machine?

Comment: This takes long the first time after an update. Before doing anything else, I would suggest waiting a little more... :)

Comment: @Jakar Yep, first thing I did was to reboot and try creating a new project.

matiash How long exactly? As I can load up Eclipse and start a project without any problems in a few minutes flat.

Comment: I figured you had, but thought it was worth checking (since I've made the mistake of not trying that before). You could check http://tools.android.com/knownissues and see if there's anything useful there. Perhaps try uninstall/reinstall if you haven't already. I don't think it should make a difference, but you could make sure your Android SDK is all the way up to date.

Comment: Experiencing same issue with Android Studio 0.8.2

Answer (score 1):

When you first create a project, it has to download a lot of stuff, including the proper distribution of Gradle and a number of dependency libraries. It's dozens of megabytes, so it can take a long time if you have a slow connection, and unfortunately, it doesn't give you a usable progress bar so you don't know how much longer it's going to take.

If it seems to be stuck forever, then check your network/proxy preferences and make sure it's set up properly.

After you create your first project, much of this information will remain cached, so future projects will start up much more quickly.

Comment: How can i adjust the proxy settings for android studio?

Answer (score 0):

If on Linux, check that you have a valid ~/.android directory.  With valid I mean: it needs to exist and have permissions for you to write to.