# Gradle stock on build ***** gradle project info

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBlof.jpg)

I have buy new macbook and I download android studio when I start new project its stock in build ..... Gradle project info
android studio last version 2.3

I try gradle work offline in setting and the same

OS X 10.9.5

java 1.8 (121)

android studio only show Building My Application Gradle project info

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong? You have to explain better. What you are currently saying is: "Something is wrong, please help me" without explaining "This is wrong, and I don't know how to fix it".

Comment: what information you need?

Comment: Stacktrace, if there is one, what you are trying to do and what fails(if something does fail)

Comment: I don't know the problem I only download the android studio and start new project and stock on build ....gradle project info

I try android studio setting under gradle and check work offline for gradle and still the same problem its stock on build ......

Comment: Open the run monitor(ALT + 4 or (in the menu at the top) View>Tool WIndows>run) and build your project(menu->build->make project) and see if any red lines show up. If no, open the Android Monitor(ALT + 6 or View>Tool windows>Android Monitor) and make sure the "Logcat" tab is active. Then rebuild the project and look for red lines. If you find red lines in either monitor, that is the error. Copy them into the question so I and others can help you solve the issue

Comment: The problem is i can't  enter to android studio i am at the first welcome page where you start new project or import  .... so i don't have view or menu ....

Comment: I add a photo about the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064792/6296561) you may just be experiencing a slow network connection. WHen a project is created for the first time there is a lot to be downloaded, and it can take a while on slow connections.

ACcording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20816095/6296561) you may be using the wrong version of android studio. If you navigate to the folder where you have Android Studio's files, look for "studio.exe" and "studio64.exe". First though, close the current open Android Studio window. Start by selecting "studio64" and opening it. Create a new project and see if it gets stuck. If it gets stuck,  try with "studio.exe" and create the project again. If it gets stuck agian, try a different solution.

And according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/21h9ok/android_studio_stuck_at_gradle_build_for_new/) you could try pressing "cancel" and finding your build.gradle on project-level. IN there you will find something like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

Replace `2.3.0` with an earlier version, e.g. 2.0.0. Then press (in the menu bar at the top) build>make project. Gradle will start to build should in theory finish.

---

If none of these work, leave a comment so I know and can look for other alternatives to these

Comment: i am using mac i don't find studio64 or studio

Comment: Look for the application files: try opening all of them(one at the time)(if there are several of them) and try to create the project again

Comment: oh i find studio and open it its open with terminal so terminal tell me what android studio do in background its downloading:

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

and i have slow internet so i need to wait? right?

Comment: Now that it is downloading, it is just to wait. The total size is(from what I have heard) about 50 MB. Depending on your internet connection, it may take a while. So it is just to wait now until it is finished

Comment: ok thank you 
I will put it solved after downloading  and run